# Dockerized MySql slower in Wifi than ethernet

Tags: docker, dockerfile, networking, mysql

When I try to connect to a MySQL server that runs in a docker container(in System A) through my application(Running in system B) via wifi, it takes at least 4X amount of time than it would when both systems are connected via ethernet. I tried adding skip-name-resolve in my.cnf and mysqld.cnf but in vain. I cannot find where the problem is and how the same can be solved!

I am attaching the dockerfile below. Thanks

[Dockerfile](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QoVXNn6dor49CCsDWUj4k0Mkyew8040tKJfKujBzqjk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: You mean that your connection is slower over wifi than over ethernet? that don't really seems a problem with mysql, docker or something else beside that it is a wifi connection. There are no real fixes beside not using wifi. It isn't the container that is slower, its your connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your mysql server running on system A and if you are trying to make connection vai wifi or sending request to make connection on mysql it is mya possible reason should be latency in network. if both system is different and you have exposed you mysql to internet then also it may happen.